# sort entries numerically with letters last

Tags: channel-entries, sort, sorting

I need to sort entries numerically on a specific field (which might include text strings) and force all the entries with a text (not integer) appearing in that field to the end of the result set.

i.e. with a data set like:

*na, 789, 123, 456*

I would want the sort by on channel:entries to return:

*123, 456, 789, na*

I'm thinking this is completely impossible without some kind of extension but... :?

Comment: I think you might need Low Alphabet for this http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet

Comment: I can confirm that Low Alphabet will help here.